# Exclude components from build using Angular Ivy

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-ivy

I am building two separate sites from a single angular project. I am using environment variables to keep track of the single site.

```js
export const getHomeComponent = (): any => {
  switch (environment.sitename) {
    case EmbassyName.BHCL:
      return HomeComponent;
    case EmbassyName.NL:
      return HomeNlComponent;
  }
};
```

I am seeing that the two components are being present in the production build. Is there a way for angular Ivy to implement tree shaking algorithm? My angular version is 11.2.14

Comment: I don't think tree shaking can solve this as this is runtime logic. The way to do this is to use provider logic I think? So in the module it belongs to, you either provide one class or the other (with a factory function or with useClass - I'm not sure).

Comment: Can you give me an example/blog link? @MikeOne

Comment: No - and now I think about it a bit more - that probably won't just work anyway. What might work is to have different environment files per language (and target those with configuration=) - where you export the correct component from. So for the NL environment file something like export { HomeNLComponent as HomeComponent  from '../../pathtocomponent'} and then import it from the environment file in the module you need it in. Not 100% sure if that simply works though? I would probably choose to conditionally lazy load either the component or the 'NL' module at runtime.

Comment: I think conditionally lazy loading the component would not exclude it from the build bundle.

Comment: It would be in the build as a separate chunk, but it would only be loaded on demand.

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeOne pointed out, a solution can be achieved by aliasing Component in the environment file.

In `environment.bhcl.ts`:

```
export { HomeComponent } from '../app/public/home/home.component';
```

And in `environment.nl.ts`:

```
export { HomeNlComponent as HomeComponent } from '../app/public/multiple-embassy/nl/home-nl/home-nl.component';
```

In the module/routing-module file I am importing `HomeComponent` and declaring it.

As a side effect I am getting circular dependency errors because of the environment file import. Maybe making a `environment-service` would solve it.

Edit: Another solution I have found is to separate the projects using `ng g application app-bhcl` etc. A library module can be created using `ng g library lib` and putting common functions there. In this way there is no way to put separate package.json, so multiple projects will have to use same node_modules.

Edit 2: Another solution is to create separate `app.modules/app-routing.modules` and replace them in `angular.json` during build/serve.

```
        {
          "replace": "src/app/app.module.ts",
          "with": "src/app/app.nl.module.ts"
        },
        {
          "replace": "src/app/app-routing.module.ts",
          "with": "src/app/app-routing.nl.module.ts"
        }
```

After that, you would then create separate modules (in my case `public.module` and `public-nl.module`) and place them in respective app/app-routing modules